# How is this python wrapper() function working?

Tags: python, wrapper

I'm having trouble understanding what is happening here with this code based on the explanation given below:

```
def route(self, path):
    def wrapper(handler):
        self.routes[path] = handler
        return handler # returns 

    return wrapper
```

Here is the explanation that was given:

> "in the route method, you took a path as an argument [note: the path here is a dictionary as follows:
> {"/home": <function home at 0x1100a70c8>} ] and in the wrapper method you added this path in the self.routes dictionary as a key and the handler as a value"

Something does not make sense here. Here are the questions I have?

1. is the wrapper(handler) inheriting its argument from route(..., path)?
2. If the handler argument is already a dictionary, i.e `{"/home": <function home at 0x1100a70c8>}`, being passed from path, how then does self.routes[path] = handler set path as a key and handler as a value? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: the snippet you've shared shouldn't do anything. you have to trigger the inner func at the top level one and maybe return it for anything to happen

Comment: This looks like part of a decorator method, which would be used as `@route("/home")`

Comment: @DevCl9 yes. That is why I mentioned the dictionary example. The top level function would be triggered and that dictionary would be passed to the path parameter in the route function.

Comment: https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/

Comment: *"is this wrapper() function builtin or is it custom?"* — This snippet `def`ines a function called "`wrapper`". Not sure what's supposed to be "builtin" about it?!

Comment: @deceze Ha yah sorry that was an absent minded question!